# How to make application overlapping with status bar which already has transparent background in Android

Tags: android, statusbar

I'm now customizing theme through some framework files. The problem is that I've made the status bar with transparent background. But there's an obvious side line between status bar and the application. How can I merge them together? Looks like the application align to the top of the screen but the status bar also exist.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please find `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_STATUS_BAR` in StatusBarService.java and replace it with `WindowManager.LayoutParams.TYPE_SYSTEM_OVERLAY`.

I think it is what you want.

Comment: That's what I exactly want! Thanks !